# Modeling discrete count data with a gamma distribution

Tags: count-data, negative-binomial-distribution, gamma-distribution

I've encountered a statistical model in which discrete count data are modeled with a gamma distribution (supported on nonnegative reals). The model relies on the property of the gamma that a sum of iid gamma rvs is also gamma, with the scale parameter multiplied by the number of rvs. However, the negative binomial shares this property and is supported on the nonnegative integers, so I would think it would be a more natural choice. One disadvantage of the NB is that its MLE doesn't have a closed form, but this is not prohibitive.

What problems could one anticipate from this modeling choice, particularly the use of a continuous density for discrete data? One issue I've identified is that it is impossible to draw 0 from a gamma distribution (it has zero density at 0, for any values of its parameters). This has implications in the larger framework that this model arises in, since counts of 0 have particular significance.

Comment: Is there any reason why you have ruled out the Poisson distribution?

Comment: You could get a positive probability for zero if you use $P(X\le k) = F_X(k+1)$ with $X$ gamma distributed.

Comment: Sounds like Gamma is not a good distribution for this value because of the reasons you give: continuous, no support for zero (and using bins would result in poor spacing for zero).

Comment: @jlimahaverford, yes the Poisson is reasonable, and also has the sum property. The NB, as a Poisson compounded with a gamma, might be favored for being more flexible (I can independently tune mean and variance).